# Simple plotting of log function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I wrote a simple function to plot log in python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = list(range(1, 10000, 1))
y = [-np.log(p/10000) for p in x]

plt.scatter(x, y) # also tried with plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

I just want to see how the plot looks.

```
fn.py:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  y = [-np.log(p/10000) for p in x]
```

I get the above error and on top of that I get a blank plot with even the ranges wrong.

It is strange why there is `divide by zero` warning, when I am dividing by a number?

How can I correctly plot the function?

Comment: Your code works as is, outputs this https://snaps.api-d.com/2019-01-30_19-37-27_wwxpv.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have tagged `python-3.x`, it seems that you are using `python-2.x` where `p/10000` will result in 0 for values of `p < 10000` because the division operator `/` performs integer division in `python-2.x`. *If that is the case*, you can explicitly use `10000.0` instead of `10000` to avoid that and get a float division.

Using `.0` is not needed in `python 3+` because by default it performs float division. Hence, your code works fine in `python 3.6.5` though

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = list(range(1, 10000, 1))
y = [-np.log(p/10000.0) for p in x]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

On a different note: You can simply use NumPy's `arange` to generate `x` and avoid the `list` completely and use vectorized operation.

```
x = np.arange(1, 10000)
y = -np.log(x/10000.0)
```

Comment: Woah good catch. I wouldn't have tought of that. For anyone wondering, this is because in python 2, deviding ints would output an int, while divividing floats & ints would return a float

Comment: @WayToDoor: Yes, indeed

Comment: @Bazingaa python --version Python 2.7.10. Caught again in python versions, thanks a lot! I am trying to avoidpython 2.7 but somehow in many places people still use it and a lot of older code is there sue to which I have to create python 2 environments and ...it goes on.

Comment: @Rafael: Let me tag python 2 in your question for sake of readers

Answer (score 1):

Why import numpy and then avoid using it?  You could have simply done:

```
from math import log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = xrange(1, 10000)
y = [-log(p / 10000.0) for p in x]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

If you're going to bring numpy into the picture, think about doing things in a numpy-like fashion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = lambda p: -np.log(p / 10000.0)
x = np.arange(1, 10000)

plt.scatter(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```